# How to adjust cell height according to WebView in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i am making app with CollectionView and data loaded from my WordPress website. I have two cells in my collection view one for posts and second for AdMob ads. I have implemented WebView to fetch posts from Website in cell but the problem is i don't know how to set cell height according to the data , i mean if post height is 100 then cell height should be 100 and if if post height is 200 then cell height should be 200.. this is my code in CollectionViewCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightWeb: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

func setup(with hukam: Post) {
    
    let htmlString:String = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"> body {font-family: \"SFUIText-Regular\"; text-align: center; font-size: 38; line-height:55px; } img { max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; } iframe { max-width: auto; width: auto; height: auto; }</style> </head><body>"+hukam.content.rendered+"</body></html>"

          self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Start loading")
    }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("End loading")
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                   self.heightWeb.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
                   
                    
                   
                })
            }
        })
        
    }
```

and when i print it in ViewController like this .

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! StatusViewCell
        
        print (cell.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        
        cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row-(indexPath.row/5)])
        
       
        heightcell = Int(cell.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        print ("Height cell is" , heightcell)
        
        return cell
```

i get the right size of webView but how can i implement it in sizeForItemAt ?

this is my code..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    var returnValue = CGSize()
    
    
        
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 960{ //Write iPhone or iPad size. If iPad :
            returnValue = CGSize(width: (((view.frame.width) - 40) / 2), height: 180)
        } else { //if iPhone
            returnValue = CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20 , height: 180)
        }
        
    
               
    return returnValue
```

this is output screenshot

[image]

please help..

Comment: *"I have two cells in my collection view..."* -- Do you mean two cell **types**? As in, AdMob cell, then many "post" cells? Or are you showing **only** two cells total?

Comment: i mean two cells types , one for showing posts and second for showing ads after X number of posts ,, @DonMag

Comment: Do you ***really*** need to use web views to display the posts? It would seem much easier and more efficient to get the post html and display it as Attributed text. It would help if you add a screenshot or two showing what you're getting.

Comment: i have updated question ,please look, yes i have tried also text but same problem , don’t know how to set height of cells according to text height

Comment: The appropriate approach, likely, is to retrieve the "post html" ... convert it to an Attributed string ... set the attributed text of the label in the cell ... and set up constraints properly to auto-size the cells. You shouldn't need to be doing any "height calculations."

Comment: how can i do that ? please can you explain a little ? thanks @DonMag

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak that language... but, the image you show looks like plain text? Or, will your "posts" have actual html formatting, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzfJJ.png

Comment: i am using textView now,, and yes its plain text now , like this  textView.text = String(htmlEncodedString:hukam.content.rendered)

Comment: If it's plain text, can't you just set the font of a label?

Comment: my problem is that all cells are of equal size, and when the text is long that doesn't fit in the cell so i can't read the full post, this is status app and i want show full status not excerpt, so i want that cell should automatically resize according to the text

Comment: OK - well, that is basic auto-layout. Is there a reason you're using a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UITableView`? Are you designing your cell in Storyboard or via code?

Comment: i am very new to this , and found UICollectionView tutorials , i am designing  cell in Storyboard

Comment: *"i am very new to this..."* - OK - I **strongly suggest** that you do some searching and go through some more tutorials to learn the basics. For what you are describing, you are doing a LOT of things you don't need to do, and using a `UITableView` makes much more sense than a `UICollectionView`. Try this as a starting point: https://www.kodeco.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells